# Connect an android device to PC (usbc-ethernet) using MQTT

Tags: java, android, usb, mqtt, ethernet

**Background:**

- I am new to MQTT and currently working on a project in which I need to connect an Android device to a PC through an adapter.
- The plan is to use MQTT protocol for connecting them and implement the MQTT client and use an open source MQTT broker.

**My questions:**

Is there any suggestion for MQTT broker? I found [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) and [moquette](https://github.com/moquette-io/moquette). Although the download link for the binary listener for the second is dead.

1. Is there any sample project that uses USBC -> ethernet for MQTT
   client and MQTT broker? (more preferably in Java as this should be
   used on Android device)
2. All examples i found online uses a URL for subscribing and publishing topics, which I assume they rely on internet/network connection. I was wondering how would be the process if the components are supposed to be connected through usbc-ethernet? Is any wrapper needed on to be used the following example in which a local host url is used for communicating between a MQTT broker and MQTT clients (borrowed the following example from this
   [git-repository](https://github.com/tgrall/mqtt-sample-java)).

**Sample implementation of using localhost for connection:**

```
  //publish 

    MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://localhost:1883", MqttClient.generateClientId());
     client.connect(); MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(); 
     message.setPayload(messageString.getBytes());
     client.publish("iot_data", message);
     System.out.println("\tMessage '"+ messageString +"' to 'iot_data'");
     client.disconnect(); 

    //subscribe

     MqttClient client=new MqttClient("tcp://localhost:1883", MqttClient.generateClientId());
     client.setCallback( new SimpleMqttCallBack() );
     client.connect();
     client.subscribe("iot_data");
```

Comment: For your first question, I've worked with https://www.emqx.io/ which was perfect both in performance and ease of use. About your second question, I did not clearly understand, but MQTT is a network protocol (run over TCP/IP) something like HTTP.

Comment: @khesam109 thanks, i will try emqx.io. But not sure whether it matters or not that it is implemented in Erlang. I thought it might be more flexible to use one which is implemented in Java.
Also regarding the second question, I assume by connecting the Android device to a PC with a USB -ethernet cable the android device should get an ip address and i may be able to use it as my endpoint. But not sure at this point since i do not have physical device yet.

Answer (score 0):

by connecting the android device to the PC, your android device should get an IP. You may be used that IP address to connect the mqtt clients to the android device (mqtt broker)